# UIScrollView content offset not working as intended

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to simulate what Apple Inc. uses in their "Messages" app, where they have a scroll view that re-adjusts itself to a proper offset if you've gone higher than the top of the scroll view content.

My scrollview takes up the entire screen, but I have a title bar which is in front of the content (like "Messages"). Upon touching the scroll view, the offset is immediately thrown away like garbage and the top content is hidden under the title bar.

My code is currently:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.scroller setDelegate:self];
    [self.scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];
    //****this offset is for the title bar****
    [self.scroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -100) animated:YES];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

and I have a function attempting to readjust the view based on y location:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 10){
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset));
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -100) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**THIS FUNCTION TAKES A LONGGGG TIME** before it re-adjusts the view.

So finally, my questions:

1. How do I make sure that on touch, the scrollview doesn't disregard the content offset, and then slowly adjust itself back to proper offset shortly after.
2. How do I change the speed at which the content offset is re-adjusted so it is similar to "Messages"?

Comment: You should add this code in `scrollViewDidEndDragging` as it is called only on user's interaction with the scrollView. Since you set it's offset in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, it changes the offset on end of deceleration. Then again, after the offset is set, `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is called again, and offset set again, and this process happens recursively.

Comment: Do not tag your question with Xcode. Read the description of the tag. It does not apply to your question.

Comment: both comments were helpful; however, switching to scrollViewDidEndDragging did not solve the problem. Strangely, loading on a simulator works fine, its when I launch via iphone there is a problem (fully up to date ios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the error to be the fact that I was using:

```
[self.scroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -100) animated:YES];
```

When I should have been using:

```
[self.scroller setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.statusbar.height,0,0,0)];
```